# my python3.10 on anaconda mac can't install python-binance

Tags: python, anaconda, binance, python-3.10

My anaconda base(root) is using python3.9, I want a new version, so I installed a new virtual environment with python3.10. Then I use"conda install -c conda-forge python-binance" to get the python-binance, but get error like below.

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-binance
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: |
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
```

I have tried all the solutions that included in this  link:https://exerror.com/solving-environment-failed-with-initial-frozen-solve-retrying-with-flexible-solve but all failed. So could anyone tell me what should I do to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried creating a fresh env specifying that you want python-binance right from the start? `conda create -n binance python python-binance`?

Comment: emmm, I didn't yet, I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this package only works for python 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 as stated in [here](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

---

So I would suggest you to downgrade your python version to be compatible with this library!

Comment: No, it works on 3.8+, at least installation should not be a problem. I'm a contributor of python-binance. The statements are just out of date and the author doesn't update it recently, though lots of new updates are only for 3.8+.